# How do I have a threesome with Yen and Triss?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I've seen the actual scene in which this occurs, but I am not sure how to get it to happen in my game.

I've played through twice and I've either gone with full Yen or full Triss. Is there a point in the story in which I could choose both and they both find out?

[Here is the scene in which I am referring to.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSp5IcQAMB0)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To have this option you have to:

1. admit love to Yen during the Quest `The Last Wish`.
2. admit love to Triss during the Quest `Now or Never`.

Then you will automatically come into the scene, also look at this video:

Comment: Wait... this video is EMBEDDED?!  How?

Comment: @Nelson Was a big surprise to me too. I don't know how. They probably supported it now? :D

Comment: Note that this influences the ending, possibly not in the way you want...

Answer (score 9):

Based on the question itself, you cannot have "a threesome" with Yen and Triss.

Based on the text within: You can continue a relationship with both, individually, throughout the game, and the scene shown in the video happens at Kaer Morhen when gathering followers if you've... well, led them both on.

Comment: Yeah, it's not really a...romantic evening. But your answer is to basically have a romantic encounter with both of them and not choose one or the other at any time?

Comment: Yep, that's it. You'll then get that cutscene at Kaer Morhen.

Comment: It's funny that you mention this scene happens at Kaer Morhen, because in the clip Yen tells Geralt to meet them at the Kingfisher Inn, which is in Novigrad, where I also experienced the same scene, after dealing with Kaer Morhen. But, essentially, yes, you have to tell both the women that you love them